# I would like to change the sticky posts label "Featured" to something else

Tags: sticky-post

On the posts that we label "sticky" the word "featured" appears. How can I change that to "new"?

David

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a theme issue.

And, if you are using TwentyEleven, the "Featured" word is printed in the file **/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/content.php**

At the very beginning you'll see

```
<h3 class="entry-format"><?php _e( 'Featured', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
```

change it for what you need

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you want "new" to be displayed, enter:

```
<?php if ( is_sticky ) { 
    echo "<h3>New</h3>";    
} ?>
```

Change h3 to whatever heading you want, or span or p or whatever else